# Calling a javascript method from the code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I need to call a JavaScript method with parameters from the code behind.

**Javascript method**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       function changeControlSample(path) 
       {
          $find('<%= PartialUpdatePanel7.ClientID %>').set_UserControlPath(path);
          $find('<%= PartialUpdatePanel7.ClientID %>').refresh();
       }
    </script>
<iucon:PartialUpdatePanel runat="server" ID="PartialUpdatePanel7" 
                        DisplayLoadingAfter="500" InitialRenderBehaviour="Clientside" EncryptUserControlPath="false">
                        <LoadingTemplate>

                             <div style="margin-left: 84px; margin-top: 10px;">
                                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/loading.gif" />
                            </div>
                            <div style="text-align: center">
                                Updating...
                            </div>
                        </LoadingTemplate>
                    </iucon:PartialUpdatePanel>
```

**The code Behind of the page**

```
protected Consultation controlconsultation  = new Consultation();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PartialUpdatePanel7.UserControlPath = "Espace_Candidat/Consultation.ascx";
           controlconsultation.imageinfo += controlconsultation_imageinfo;
           Session["controlconsultation"] = controlconsultation;
        }
    void controlconsultation_imageinfo(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
    {
       PartialUpdatePanel7.UserControlPath = "Espace_Candidat/InfoEdition.ascx";
       Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
                                              "CallMyFunction",   
        "changeControlSample('Espace_Candidat/InfoEdition.ascx')", true);
    }
```

**Code behind of the user control**

```
public event CommandEventHandler imageinfo ; 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 Consultation current = (Consultation)Session["controlconsultation"];
                imageinfo = current.imageinfo;
       }
  protected void Valider (object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
          {
            if (imageinfo != null)
              {
                  string pageNumber = (string)e.CommandArgument;
                  CommandEventArgs args = new CommandEventArgs("Control", pageNumber);
                  imageinfo(this, args);
              }
          }
```

This call didn't work even I change the JavaScript method by another one.

For example, if I try

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
(this.GetType(), 
"CallMyFunction", 
"alert('blabla');", 
 true);
```

I got the same result.

1. So, What is the error that I commited?
2. How can I fix my code?

Comment: In what way did it not work?  Any errors generated in the browser?

Comment: No, but the method is not called , see the example i mentionned

Comment: How are you calling "controlconsultation_imageinfo" ?

Comment: @SurajSingh the event is raised from another user control and handled here in this page. The goal of this js method is to change the current user control. My problem is that even i change the js method i don't get a result

Comment: @SurajSingh see please my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have update panel in page then call like this,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), @"<script type='text/javascript'>changeControlSample('" + path + "');</script>", false);
```

It don't have update panel then call like this

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "tabselect", "<script type='text/javascript'>changeControlSample("' + path  + '");</script>");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to call JavaScript method with parameters from the code behind you can get this done using

> ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method

please check the link given below:

> [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.