# how to call javascript function in Web user Control ascx

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have the following Code on test.ascx **ASP Control**:

```
  function mute() {       
        var button_mute = document.getElementById('<%= btnRequestCompanyCheck.ClientID %>');
        button_mute.style.display = "none";
        alert("x");

    }
```

How I can call mute() from Code behind (test.ascx.cs), I am trying all of below list, no one is working for me.
Which one should I used on **Asp.net Control**?

```
ScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this, this.GetType(), "test", "mute()");
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "test", "mute()", true);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "test", "mute()", true);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "test", "mute()", true);
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction","mute()", true);
```

Comment: mute() is supposed to occur in the browser in response to an event handler on the server? how is the server supposed to send that message to the client? is the event handler running as a full postback or partial postback? We need more info to help.

Comment: @Tetsujion .. I used ImageButton_OnClickEvent to call mute() javascript

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni .. so when the user Click on ImageButton i hide the Image button and add new text ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a javascript method from the code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606389/calling-a-javascript-method-from-the-code-behind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried this?

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="javascript:return mute();" />
```

And here is the javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mute() {
    alert("Muted");

    return false;
}
</script>
```

Here is the code behind alternative

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", "mute()", true);
```

Comment: thanks ..i trying to do that before .. it is working ..but i have some validation from code behind ,so i need to call script function from code behind ..

Comment: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", "mute()", true);...Not working ..:(.. i used this code inside ImageButton_onClick() event ..

Comment: Not working means? Are you not any responses / any script errors?

Comment: no Response.. and no java SCript Error .. i used WebDevloper-->webConsole in FireFox

Comment: can view source and did you see something like this? `<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
mute()//]]>
</script>`

Comment: i view the source and find :<script type="text/javascript">
    
    function mute() {       
        var button_mute = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_container_container_Block_183_onePage_paymentOption_tbcPaymentOptions_tbpOfflinePayment_btnRequestCompanyCheck');
        button_mute.style.display = "none";
        alert("x");
        return false;
    }
</script>...without //<![CDATA[ mute()//]]>

Comment: That's strange. Ideally it should render `<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ mute()//]]> </script>` Not sure why it is not rendering in your page.

Comment: I update the question could you please vote up ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to register `ScriptManager` on parent control like

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

after you can use,

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "indexonchange", "OnIndexChange();", true);
```

Comment: could you please add how to call it from code behind ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "test", "javascript:mute();", true);
```

Comment: javascript:mute();
try without ";"

Comment: try remove all the code from the mute() function and test it with only alert message to know if it works or not

Comment: no problem in mute() function ..mute running correctly from onClientClick event .. but i am trying to call it from code behind ..